# Angular animate query returning zero elements

Tags: html, angular

Using Angular, I wanted to make an animated display list. The problem is that I am getting this error:

[image]

Objects are in the array and show up on the screen, but are not animated.

This is what the HTML code looks like, where I iterate through the table and display the elements that I want to be slowly displayed (animation):

```
 <section [@listAnimation]="articles.length">
            <div *ngFor="let article of articles">
              <div class="card border-0">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
                    <div class="container-text-image">
                      <img [src]="article.mainImageSrc" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='..\..\..\assets\notFound.png';" class="card-img" [alt]="article.mainImageFullName">
                      <div class="label bottom-left">
                        <h3 class="label-text">
                          {{article.category}}
                        </h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title mt-0">{{article.title}}</h5>
                      <p *ngIf="article.description != null" class="card-text description-text">{{article.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
```

This is what the animation code looks like in a component:

```
const listAnimation = trigger('listAnimation', [
  transition('* <=> *', [
    query(':enter',
      [style({ opacity: 0 }), stagger('60ms', animate('600ms ease-out', style({ opacity: 1 })))],

    ),
    query(':leave',
      animate('200ms', style({ opacity: 0 })),

    )
  ])
]);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-articles',
  templateUrl: './articles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./articles.component.css'],
  animations: [listAnimation]
})
```

Here's a snippet of code where I get my backend data into an array:

```
private fetchArticles = (): void => {
    this.loaderService.show();
    this.articlesService
      .getPortalArticles(this.getArticlesParams())
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.setArticleMainImg();
          this.loaderService.hide();
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
          this.articlesCount = result.totalItemsCount;
          this.articles = result.items;
        },
        (error) => { }
      );
  }
```

Any ideas what might be causing the error? I realize that I can add `{optional: true}` to the animation code, but this will only get rid of the error and the animation will still not work.